# Add text next to UI Form action icon in toolbar?

Tags: forms, user-interface, button, action, toolbar

Is there a way to add text next to the action icon in the toolbar of an eclipse RCP UI Form? If you do not assign the Action an ImageDescriptor, the action will be displayed containing only text. If you do give it an ImageDescriptor, it displays only the image. I want to display both side by side, within one button - is there a way to do this?

This will have only the text "Description" in the button on the toolbar:

```
myAction = new Action("Description", SWT.PUSH) {
               @Override
               public void run() {}
           };

myForm.getToolBarManager().add(myAction);
```

But adding an image will cause the the text to be replaced:

```
myAction.setImageDescriptor(newImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to find an answer to my issue, hopefully it's helpful to anyone else who runs into this problem. I found this in the Eclipse Rich Client Platform (2nd Ed.) book.

The Action must be converted to an ActionContributionItem with its mode set to MODE_FORCE_TEXT. This will display both the text and the image in the toolbar.

```
ActionContributionItem aCI = new ActionContributionItem(myAction);
aCI.setMode(ActionContributionItem.MODE_FORCE_TEXT);
myForm.getToolBarManager().add(aCI);
```